# Regular expressions in JS (select tags from string)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
some description +first tag, +second tag (tags separated by commas)
+third tag +fourth tag (tags separated by space)
+tag from new line (it's just one tag)
+tag1+tag2+tag3 (tags can follow each other)
```

How can I select all tag names from this string?

1) Tag can contain several words,
2) tag always starts with + sign, 
3) tag ends with either next tag, or newline, or comma

Comment: I've tried to split the string by lines, then by ','. So I have array of substrings. Then I need to extracts tags from each substring. It's a little bit easy than from initial string, but I still don't know how to do it :)

Comment: so what result are you after? Something like {first: "tag",second: "tag (tags sepearated by commas}",third: "tag",fourth: "tag (tags separated by space)",tag:"from new line (it's just one tag)", tag1tag2tag3 : "(tags can follow each other)"}

Comment: just a plain array of tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd give this a shot:

```
var str = "some description +first tag, +second tag\n" +
   "+third tag +fourth tag\n" +
   "+tag from new line\n" +
   "+tag1+tag2+tag3";
var tags = str.match(/\+[^+,\n\s].+?(?=\s*[\+,\n]|$)/g);
```

this results in `tags` with this:

```
[ '+first tag',
  '+second tag',
  '+third tag',
  '+fourth tag',
  '+tag from new line',
  '+tag1',
  '+tag2',
  '+tag3' ]
```

To elaborate:

```
\+          // Starts with a '+'.
[^+,\n\s]   // Doesn't end immedatedly (empty tag).
.+?         // Non-greedily match everything.
(?=         // Forward lookahead (not returned in match).
  \s*       // Eat any trailing whitespace.
  [\+,\n]|$ // Find tag-ending characters, or the end of the string.
)
```

Comment: it doesn't grab the last tag "tag3"

Comment: ok, I can append an additional \n at the end of the string :)

Comment: You need to add `$` to your lookahead (i.e. `(?=\s*([\+,\n]|$))`), but +1

Comment: It's almost as awesome as this:
http://www.topito.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/code-03.gif

Comment: @mVChr Good call, updated.
@Iidar, adding the `$` is a better way that adding an extra `\n`.